# Verilog forcing struct to be packed

Tags: struct, verilog, system-verilog

I have a struct declared inside a module like this:

```
module myModule;

  struct {
    logic a;
    logic b;
    logic [A - 1:0] c[0:B - 1];
    logic [C - 1:0] d;
  } [D - 1:0] e [0:E - 1][0:F - 1];

endmodule
```

I want to use `c` like an unpacked array, but Verilog does not allow this.  It throws an error on the line where `c` is defined:

```
Unsupported: Unpacked array in packed struct/union
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Since `c` is an unpacked variable, you can not used `packed` structures of SV. The following will work: `typedef struct packed{ logic a; logic b; logic [A - 1:0] c[0:B - 1]; logic [C - -1:0] d;  } mystruct; mystruct e [0:E - 1][0:F - 1];` Note that `e` should not have a packed dimension since it is an array of struct variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have a packed array, all element must be packed. So either make the struct packed:

```
struct packed {
    logic a;
    logic b;
    logic [A - 1:0] [0:B - 1] c;
    logic [C - 1:0] d;
  } [D - 1:0] e [0:E - 1][0:F - 1];
```

or make the e array all unpacked

```
  struct {
        logic a;
        logic b;
        logic [A - 1:0] [0:B - 1] c;
        logic [C - 1:0] d;
      } e [0:E - 1][0:F - 1][D - 1:0];
```

BTW, it is highly recommended that you use a `typedef` for your struct instead of having an anonymous struct type.

Comment: Thanks.  The solution was both to mark the struct as packed and to make the e array unpacked.  I added a typedef for the struct as well.

Comment: How can this be solved if the struct is just a single item? `struct { ... } e;`?

Comment: @Moberg the answer to the original question does not change if the `struct` has a single item. (Like just element `c`)

Comment: @dave_59 I meant the case where `e` is not an array at all, for example: is `struct { logic [A - 1:0] c[0:B - 1]; } e;` legal? I get an error with the same wording, but in my case it might just be that Verilator doesn't support unpacked arrays in structs at all.

Comment: Unpacked structs can contain *any* type.

Comment: @dave_59 how do I force the struct to be unpacked? Since I still get the error with this code `struct { logic [A - 1:0] c[0:B - 1]; } e;`

Comment: Structs are unpacked by default. You probably need to post this as a new question with a complete example in the exact error message you’re getting

Comment: Ok thanks. It was an open issue for Verilator with a slightly misleading error message: https://github.com/verilator/verilator/issues/1541